# Magento 1.9 Custom Module Image Upload

Tags: php, magento

I would like some help uploading two images in my module

my controller looks like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
                try {   

                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');


                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }


                $data['filename'] = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            }


            if(isset($_FILES['filename_mobile']['name']) && $_FILES['filename_mobile']['name'] != '') {
                try {   

                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename_mobile');


                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);


                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);


                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'mobile'.DS;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename_mobile']['name'] );

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }


                $data['filename_mobile'] = $_FILES['filename_mobile']['name'];
            }
```

and my form is like this:

```
 $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('configuracao')->__('Banner Desktop'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'filename',
      ));

      $fieldset->addField('filename_mobile', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('configuracao')->__('Banner Mobile'),
        'required'  => false,
        'name'      => 'filename_mobile',
    ));
```

when I save, the database is "Array" and the thumbnail also says "Array"

where am i wrong could someone please help me?

Comment: Could please var_dump($_FILES['filename_mobile] [' name']) and provide here.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry 
I remove or modulate the core_resource table and install it again, and it worked out fine